# Linked documents across databases in CouchDb

Tags: couchdb

I've been reading about [Linked documents](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents) in the CouchDb documentation, it seems fine and all.

But is it possible to write a view in Database A that emits a document from Database B? I need it because we store different types in different databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't work. You should store different-but-related types in the same database.